# Can I accidentally push more than one Git feature branch at the same time?

Tags: git, git-push, git-config

I've been using `git` for a few years now, so I'd say I'm "comfortable" with it but am by no means an expert.

Started a new job and my dev lead is trying to tell me that if I don't periodically delete/prune my local feature branches using `git remote update origin --prune` that `git` will **auto-push them occassionally when pushing OTHER feature branches!!!**

As an example of what he's saying here, let's say I've got a project called `myproject` which has the following branches:

- `master`
- `develop`
- `feature/one`
- `feature/two`
- `feature/three`

Let's say `feature/one` and `feature/two` are old and have already been pushed to GitHub, merged to `develop`, and deleted from GitHub (the origin). `feature/three` is what I'm currently working on.

He's saying that if I don't `git remote update origin --prune` periodically, that I run the risk of re-pushing `feature/one` and `feature/two` to GitHub when I go to finally push my `feature/three` branch via `git push`!

This statement, if true, would not only shock me, it would leave me *thunderstruck!* Is it true, false, or partially correct, and why?!

Comment: I generally recommend against pruning local branches using this command, if someone deletes your branch on the remote, it will be deleted locally even if you still need it. (Unless you particularly like having dates with ref-log.) I prefer to only delete merged branches in batch (and explicitly delete branches that have not). I have an alias for this command, which only deletes merged branches. `git branch --merged origin/master | grep -v "*" | xargs git branch -D`. Fetch first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Git 2.0 the default `push.default` config is set to `simple`. Only the current branch is pushed if it is connected with a remote tracking branch and the names are matching: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.

Before, in Git 1.x., the default was `matching`. With this configuration all local branches with a equal named remote tracking branch were pushed together. If you had stale remote tracking branches, it could happen, that a `git push` re-created a removed remote branch.

Maybe your dev lead is still on Git 1.x. or your team decided to use the old `matching` behavior as default.

Answer (score 3):

`git` will not auto-push branches.  But you of course could accidentally [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) the incorrect branch when you do [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) `feature/three`.  For example, you could accidentally type `git push origin feature/one` instead of `git push origin feature/three`.  That doesn't have anything to do with `git`, but it would be a user error.  You could also accidentally use the `--all` flag when you did not intend to, for example.

Additionally, if you do accidentally push the wrong `branch`, then just delete the `remote branch` when you realize your mistake (`git push origin :feature/one`).  Since the `remote branch` has already been `merged`, it would not negatively impact anything.

Comment: That being said, removing your local branches is still a good practice

Answer (score 3):

This can also have something to do with the `push.default` setting in your git config (see the detailed doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault)).

Basically, it's used to set the expected behaviour for a `git push` (no arguments).

When you explicitly give arguments to the push command, it proceeds as it's told, but it's often the case that people forget what is their default setting (or just ignore its existence), try to push, and if their default is to push every branch to its remote counterpart*, well... it might just be what your coworker hinted at with this "auto-push" thing.

* The standard changed since git 2.0 from `matching` (push each branch to its counterpart) to `simple` (just push current branch).

Comment: I just wrote the exact same answer, but was 5 minutes to late :-)

Answer (score 1):

Besides what others have said you could accidentally execute

```
git push :
```

From git-push Manual:

> The special refspec : (or +: to allow non-fast-forward updates) directs Git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side.